# Google maps getting longitude

Tags: php, google-maps

I am using the Google Maps api to get the coordinates of locations using the following code:

```
$q = "Miami Florida"; //example location to query
$api_key = "ABQIAAAA...";

$handle = fopen("http://maps.google.com/maps/geo?q=".urlencode($q)."&sensor=false&oe=utf8&gl=en&output=csv&key=".$api_key,"r");
$data = fgetcsv($handle); ?>

<?php echo $data[0]; ?> <br />
Latitude: <?php echo $data[2]; ?> <br />
Longitude: <?php echo $data[1]; ?>
```

It returns the correct latitude (25.7889689) but the longitude is always one digit like 4 or 5.. This happens with any location I query. Also data[0] should be an accuracy search but it returns `200`.. not sure if that's right.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're using the wrong index for longitude

http://maps.google.com/maps/geo?q=new+haven+ct&sensor=false&oe=utf8&gl=en&output=csv

You want `$data[3]`.

`$data[1]` is the accuracy

Answer (score 2):

The first element is a server response code, which in your case is 200 letting you know it was successful. The second element is the accuracy. The third and fourth are the latitude and longitude, respectively.

When I entered http://maps.google.com/maps/geo?q=23943&sensor=false&oe=utf8&gl=en&output=csv into my browser I received the following output:

200,5,33.4954920,-86.8094808

If you replace the csv output with json you'll get back a more human friendly version.